# jQuery click driven slideshow (cycle plugin)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

This may seem like a very basic question, since I'm not familiar with jQuery,  but I'm having some trouble with implementing the jquery cycle plugin.  I have found the code for the previous/next off the Jquery Cycle Plugin page: [jQuery Cycle Plugin - Intermediate Demos (Part 2)](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html) (Previous/Next example)

So far I have this
 [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcNcx/q8Cam/) as a test

This is the jQuery of the animation effects that I would like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#s2').cycle({ 
   fx:     'slideY', 
   speed:   300, 
   timeout: 0, 
   next:   '#next2', 
   prev:   '#prev2' 
  });
});
```

I have the buttons in place, along with some test images, but I'm having trouble getting the animation from the button to work.

I have read the documentation of the cycle options, but since I'm not too familiar with jQuery I don't understand how to get it to work, I have the fx and speed ready, just getting the buttons to work is my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `<a>` tag for the buttons. For example:

```
<a id="prev2" href="#">Prev</a>
```

Then use CSS to style it how you would like.

Make sure you include the cycle.js once after the jquery framework as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've tried doing that, but I still can't get the animation to work, I've updated the jsfiddle with the `<a>` tag and I still can't implement it properly, I tried it out with dreamweaver as well and same result

Comment: I tidied up your code a bit and it's now working http://jsfiddle.net/q8Cam/14/. You included some inline styles for the images which were not necessary and an include to the cycle.js which you doubled up.

Comment: Thanks so much :) so it was the inline style which was messing with it?

Comment: more likely the double up of the cycle.js. You included it in the javascript area and the managed resources tab. In a normal web page just make sure its included once below the jquery library. I'll update my answer to show this.